# RegEx use one for both cases?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Okay well, here's the string

```
$string = "123456789_some_0.png";
```

i currently use preg_match to get the " 123456789 " using the following pattern :

```
$pattern = "/[0-9]*/i";
```

well, there are 2 formats for the string, i want to come up with the same result for this case :

```
$string = "1234-123456789_some_0.png";
```

and to come up with " 12345789 " and only from both cases,
how to do it ?

Comment: Why not match `1234` in the second string? What's the exact rule you want to match? It has to have more than 4 digits?

Comment: @JoãoSilva 1234 is just an example, its actually a variable that changes everytime with random numbers

Comment: Yes, but in the second string you want to match `123456789`, not `1234`. Why is that? Because `123456789` is followed by an underscore?

Comment: @JoãoSilva Yup.. your answer below helped though, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to capture all digits that are followed by an underscore, you could use the following:

```
$strings = array("1234-123456789_some_0.png", "123456789_some_0.png");
foreach ($strings as $string) {
  preg_match("/([0-9]+)_/", $string , $matches);
  echo $matches[1], PHP_EOL; // 123456789
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/cs9lt)**.